# Plotar fatores (spp) de metaMDS em ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quero plotar as espécies nos agrupamentos do resultado do metaMDS usando ggplot. Tentei assim, mas dá erro:Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (20): label.

```
library(dune)
data(dune)
sol <- metaMDS(dune)
spp<-names(dune)
mds1<-sol$points[,1]
mds2<-sol$points[,2]
sol1<-cbind(dune,mds1,mds2)
ggplot(sol1,aes(mds1,mds2))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(label=spp))
```

Sei porque o erro ocorre. A quantidade de linhas e colunas é diferente, mas não sei como fazer para corrigi-lo ou se pode ser corrigido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O objeto `sol` já tem todas as informações necessárias para criar o multidimensional scaling plot.

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
sol <- metaMDS(dune)
```

Em particular, veja as informações presentes dentro de `sol$species`:

```
sol$species
#>                 MDS1        MDS2
#> Achimill -0.82281011  0.04326590
#> Agrostol  0.71096673 -0.28923350
#> Airaprae -0.52824471  1.67985459
#> Alopgeni  0.39097510 -0.58595238
#> Anthodor -0.72024342  0.65912703
#> Bellpere -0.47837443 -0.24447599
#> Bromhord -0.61896319 -0.33477103
#> Chenalbu  0.59187735 -0.92196207
#> Cirsarve -0.15182360 -0.82170787
#> Comapalu  1.28932890  0.60841273
#> Eleopalu  1.24505152  0.16150523
#> Elymrepe -0.42013221 -0.68024533
#> Empenigr -0.08839391  1.69631104
#> Hyporadi -0.41574036  1.44599800
#> Juncarti  0.91146527 -0.08307932
#> Juncbufo  0.26477479 -0.60759446
#> Lolipere -0.51198132 -0.24808035
#> Planlanc -0.70645461  0.32062556
#> Poaprat  -0.38843320 -0.25092040
#> Poatriv  -0.15905975 -0.47836891
#> Ranuflam  1.14364071  0.09955908
#> Rumeacet -0.52478430 -0.10531078
#> Sagiproc  0.14315709 -0.18744430
#> Salirepe  0.57483100  0.91107541
#> Scorautu -0.13957081  0.25000786
#> Trifprat -0.77153459  0.08563492
#> Trifrepe -0.07526533  0.04517137
#> Vicilath -0.46793723  0.54915464
#> Bracruta  0.15072189  0.18980509
#> Callcusp  1.42117957  0.38378896
#> attr(,"shrinkage")
#>      MDS1      MDS2 
#> 0.5160467 0.3713241 
#> attr(,"centre")
#>        MDS1        MDS2 
#> -0.02324753 -0.05510302
```

Perceba que todas as informações sobre as coordenadas dos pontos e das suas respectivas espécies estão neste objeto. Agora basta criar um data frame apropriado e, a partir dele, criar o gráfico desejado.

```
sol1 <- data.frame(sol$species, spp = rownames(sol$species))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(sol1, aes(x = MDS1, y = MDS2))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(label = spp))
```

[image]

Comment: No meu caso ainda preciso relacionar as espécies com os lugares onde foram coletadas e mostrar no gráfico. Talvez seja melhor editar a pergunta ou fazer uma nova pergunta com um df similar ao meu.

Comment: Exatamente. Quanto mais próximo da realidade for o conjunto de dados fornecido e mais completa for a pergunta, maior a probabilidade de alguém respondê-la de maneira útil. Acho mais produtivo fazer uma pergunta nova, pois uma edição como essa alteraria muito o pergunta original.